# How to use JSDoc to document and enforce typing for components composed with higher-order components

Tags: reactjs, jsx, jsdoc

Let's imagine I have the following HOC in React 18+:

```js
/**
 * @param { LoadingCardProps } config 
 */
export const withLoader = (config) => {
  /**
   * @template P
   * @param { ReactComponent<P> } Component 
   */
  const DecoratedComponent = (Component) => {
    /**
     * @param { P & WithLoaderProps } props
     * @returns { ReactNode }
     */
    const ComponentWithLoader = (props) => {
      if (props.isLoading) {
        return LoadingCard(config);
      }
      return Component(props);
    };

    return ComponentWithLoader;
  };
  return DecoratedComponent;
};
```

I've tried to document it as something generic, just so that I could keep code assist (autocomplete) working when using the component in JSX.

I tried using it like this:

```js
/**
 * @typedef { object } LoadedComponentProps
 * @property { string } content
 */

/**
 * 
 * @param { LoadedComponentProps } props 
 * @returns { ReactNode }
 */
const LoadedComponent = ({ content }) => {
  return <div>{ content }</div>;
};

const DecoratedLoadedComponent = withLoader({ message: 'Wait a bit, things are loading...' })(LoadedComponent);
```

If I try using the `LoadedComponent` directly in JSX, I get code assist just as expected. But trying to use the `DecoratedLoadedComponent` simply shows no code assist, as I haven't typed the `@template P` when using `withLoader`.

How should I proceed about this? How can I correctly type the result of using `withLoader`? I was able to do this in TypeScript but JSDoc is eluding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting here, I decided to try some more alternatives I hadn't tried yet - `@name`, `@namespace` and finally `@callback`, as per some other S.O. answers to different problems than mine. In the end, even though it makes things a bit idiotic - I have to document both the HOC **and** it's result when used - I have the code assist I wanted, as well as make it harder for other devs in my team to screw up component props.

The solution was to create a `@callback` signature for the resulting component after using my HOC's, and using that as the `@type` as follows:

```js
/**
 * @callback DecoratedLoadedComponent
 * @param { LoadedComponentProps & WithLoaderProps } props
 * @returns { ReactNode }
 */

/**
 * @type { DecoratedLoadedComponent }
 */
const DecoratedLoadedComponent = withLoader({ message: 'Wait a bit, things are loading...' })(LoadedComponent);
```